# Discrete-Math The combination of a certain combination lock consists...

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The combination of a certain combination lock consists of three numbers from 1 through 20 in a sequence with no two consecutive numbers the same. How many different combinations are possible?

This is very difficult and I couldn't figure out the answer. Can anyone help me?

Also I had a question in mind, I am a computer science major and I'm currently taking discrete math. Discrete math consists of all logic questions. This question is based on logic, though I couldn't figure it out. Computer science is all about logic, does a typical "good" computer scientist able to figure this problem out logically without any help? In other words, you need to have a good way of thinking/ logic to become a computer scientist. You should be able to solve complicated problems if you want to become a "good" programmer. Is this an easy question that a computer science major student should be able to answer in top of his head? Idk if that made any sense but your answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If all three numbers are different, then clearly there are $20 \cdot 19 \cdot 18$ possible combinations.  The only other possibility is if the first and last number are equal.  This can be achieved in $20 \cdot 19 \cdot 1$ ways (there is only one way to choose the third number if we say it is equal to the first number).  So the total number of valid combinations is $20 \cdot 19 \cdot 18 + 20 \cdot 19 = 20 \cdot 19 \cdot 19.$